# How to run PLINK on m1 MacBook

Tags: genetics

I am a new user of PLINK. I installed plink1.07 on the website and followed the instruction. However, my terminal returned no file when I type `./plink`.

Here is the return:

```
zsh: no such file or directory: ./plink
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a m1 macbook user too. I downloaded the file for intel mac, but it reveals that I am using the wrong cpu. So maybe the m1 macbooker now can't use plink on a macsystem. But through the parallels desktop, I can use it.

Comment: I am a m1 macbook user too. I download the file for intel mac,but it reveals that i use the wrong cpu. So maybe m1 macbooker now can't use plink on macsystem. But through parallels desktop i can use it despite the low speed of operation. Hoped that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get Plink 1.07 to work on my M1 chip. I tried switching my arch to x86 (rosetta) but this still yields a wrong cpu error.

Unless you specifically need PLINK 1.07 I would highly recommend using PLINK 1.9. The 1.9 MAC version is compatible with ARM arch and is much faster than plink 1.07.

https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/